# .HTACCESS subdomain redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having an issue with subdomain.. i have a subdomain content.domain.com
which i want to use for cookieless domain content..

but when i wrote it in website.. its automatically add full website url.. which i have added in .htaccess

can you please let me know how can i stop redirecting the subdomain ....

**Please help......**

here is code for htaccess for domain redicretion

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: both have got `R`edirect flags

Comment: so what to do that its not redirect the subdomain? the above code is used to add https: and www in a url...which is necessary..

Answer (score 1):

1. You can combine both rules into a single rule
2. Using a `RewriteCond` you can omit a subdomain.

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!content\.domain\.com)(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache while testing this change.

Comment: okay.. but i dont want to add https: and www with teh subdomain.. still this will work ???

Comment: Yes it will skip your subdomain for both `https` and `www` adding. Make sure you replace both of your rules with this rule.